# How to remove duplicated words in file using scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have A CSV file which contains duplicated words.each file contains three column UseId,MovieId,genres.
I want to find duplicate words in genres.

sample of data in file:

[image]

I want to remove duplicate of words.
I try this but not worked

```
    val distinctDF = Data.dropDuplicates()
 distinctDF.write.csv("file:///usr/local/comedyDistinct")
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Two files have the same dupliate data and I want only the names of genres. Iles have the same semantics in the dataset.

Comment: What do you expect as result from the example you gave? I mean if there is a row with the same `genre` values in the 2 files, which one you keep?

Comment: I want remove the duplication only.

Comment: use row_number: `df.withColumn("rn", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("genres"))).filter("rn = 1").drop("rn")`

Comment: I can't determine each row number .It's a big file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to delete duplicate on the basis of a single column, not the entire row.

```
 val distinctDF = Data.dropDuplicates("genres")
 distinctDF.write.csv("file:///usr/local/comedyDistinct")
```